# How can I add all the values resulting from "for clause"?

Tags: python

Here is my code:

```
from __future__ import division
import nltk
import string
import re
import math
from nltk import bigrams

f = open('C:/Python27/brown_A1_half.txt', 'rU')
w = open('C:/Python27/brown_A1_half_Out.txt', 'w')

#to read whole file using read()

filecontents = f.read()
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize
sent_tokenize_list = sent_tokenize(filecontents)
result = ''
new_sentences = ["Start " + sentence + " End " for sentence in sent_tokenize_list]
result = ''.join(new_sentences)

tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(result)
#print tokens
bi_tokens = tuple(nltk.bigrams(tokens))
#print bi_tokens
bi_freq = nltk.FreqDist(bi_tokens)
for k, v in bi_freq.items():
print k, v
```

This result `bigram` and `value(=its frequency")`.

How can I add all the values in this for loop? That means, `v1` + `v2` + `v3` … `vn`. I can't use `sum` function.

Comment: What do you mean you can't use `sum` function? Where did you use it and how?

Comment: Learn how to use [loops](http://www.learnpython.org/en/Loops). In your previous question also, you had the same problem.

Comment: here, bi_freq 's type is class.nltk.probability.FreqDist. and "k" is tuple, "v" is int. I learned sum function can be applied to the list type. but here what I obtained by my codes are tuple, int, tuple, int, tuple, int.......... what I want is sum every int values here..

Comment: @YounginNa If you look at my answer, you can see how can you use `sum` function in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just replace your last two lines with this:

```
v_sum = 0
for k, v in bi_freq.items():
    v_sum += v
    print k, v
```

Answer (score 2):

If `v` is just a number, you could `sum` all theese values from the `bi_freq` as:

```
sum(bi_freq.itervalues())
```

`bi_freq.itervalues()` will get all the values from `bi_freq` and then `sum` will add those with each other.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that v is a list structure.

```
v = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

result = 0 
for items in v:
    result += items

print(result)
```

prints "55"